# C# Facebook webhook api returned JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, facebook-graph-api

im trying to implement Facebook Real Time Update (webhook) , i do all the steps in the Facebook graph API documentation, and the result was JSON contain only few information about the change.

i want to get more information in the JSON result when user upload a delete a photo to his account , like getting new photo id,url or specify what is the real change.

these some photos for my webhook setting and result in codebehind

[Webhook image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0WjQ.jpg)

[JSON result in code behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLf0p.png)

Answer (score 0):

To get more details, you will have to use the id to fetch the object using Graph API Get request. Then you may be able to compare the result with the previous values. Webhooks returns specific data inside entry object as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks